# python3 convert utf-8 to cp852

Tags: python-3.x, encoding

I have a dictionery, keys were parsed from xls by xlrd, there are filenames, some are in utf-8 and some in something else maybe cp852. I need a map data values through filenames from os.listdir, but some keys are in other encoding.

```
def translateTo( self, czechName, toLang ) :
    # language orig, here is not used
    # cz lang is used as key, therefore -2 

    if czechName in self.dictionary.keys() :
        return self . dictionary [ czechName ][ toLang - 2 ];
    else :
        return czechName
```

when i use this code dictionery works like dependent on battery.
problem:

```
>>> 'HELUZ H4 - komíny.xml' == 'HELUZ H4 - komíny.xml'
```

`False`
on left is sting in maybe cp852, on lef side is that string in classic utf-8

how can i make true? Is posible to define self comparator to dictionery in python?

Comment: Ifthat is Python 3 - this means taht both strings are already "decoded" to Python's internal unicode format. neither utf-8 nor cp852 isa playing a role there (they would have need the prefix "b" if they were encoded, and they would not look the same - the strign with encoding different than the terminal would be broken), The "normalize" solution you foundshows that the encoding process had gone in a different way for both - one had the "í", another used the unicode composite sequence to create the diacritical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it!

normalize( 'NFKD', 'HELUZ H4 - komíny.xml' ) == normalize( 'NFKD', 'HELUZ H4 - komíny.xml' )

True